# Algorithm to minimize least squares when doing allocation?

Tags: algorithm, math, mathematical-optimization, quadratic-programming

Suppose we have to allocate x amount to k desired amounts.  Is there algorithm to do this that minimizes the squared distance between the actual k allocated values and the k desired amounts?

For example suppose we need to allocate x=5 to k=3 desired amounts of 2,-3,4.

We could allocate the 5 to 2,-3,6 producing squared distance of 0^2 + 0^2 + 2^2 = 4.

We are allowed to allocate negative amounts or any amount to the k amounts.  The only restriction is the allocated amounts must sum to original x.  Also allocated amounts do not need to be integers, only real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Let y be the sum of the desired amounts and let d be the difference between x and y. The minimum is obtained by distributing d equally among the k desired amounts. Exercise for the reader: prove this using Lagrangian multipliers.

In the given example, y = 2 - 3 + 4 = 3 and d = 5 - 3 = 2. Allocating d=2 evenly to the k desired values means adding 2/3 to each of the items, leading to an allocation of 2 2/3, -2 1/3, and 4 2/3.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches come to mind:

1. [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). Ideal for minimizing a quadratic cost function with a linear constraint. The link provides several example on how to setup and solve the problem.

   [image: cost]

   [image: lagrange]

   which yields

   [image: lambda1]

   applying the constraint and defining

   [image: y]

   gives

   [image: lambda2]

   substituting back gives the final solution

   [image: soln]

   In other words, we compute the difference between the total desired outputs and total constraint and divide it equally among them.
2. [Fair division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_division). If you are willing to relax the least squares criteria your problem might be solveable using fair division techniques. In particular, [adjusted winner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjusted_winner_procedure) is a way of fairly allocating goods among players. You won't get negative answers like you suggested but is more like a cake cutting solution.

Answer (score 0):

Basically for vector v (of length k) of data and total budget b, you have the following optimization problem:

```
min_{x1, x2, ..., xk} (x1-v1)^2 + (x2-v2)^2 + ... + (xk-vk)^2
s.t. x1 + x2 + ... + xk = b
```

This is a linearly constrained quadratic program, which can be solved using quadratic programming software packages. For instance, here's a solution with the `quadprog` package in the R language:

```
# Setup data
v <- c(2, -3, 4)
b <- 5

# Solve quadratic program
library(quadprog)
solve.QP(diag(length(v)), v, matrix(rep(1, length(v))), b, 1)$solution
# [1]  2.666667 -2.333333  4.666667
```

In this example, we get objective value 4/3, smaller than the objective value of 4 for the allocation provided in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case LP.  The minimum is always achieved by allocating such that your delta-k values are all the same.

Since the objective function is sum of squares, and all data points are equally weighted, allocating other than same-value delta-ks results in a higher sum of squares.  (Note that in josilber's quadprog solution the delta-k values are all 2/3.  There's a proof hiding somewhere in partial derivative land that I'm too tired or dumb to work out.)